# Putting strings in Python lists

Tags: python

I am trying to make a dynamic map for a text-based RPG that I am coding, so I tried this array:

```
landscape = [['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,X']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']
['O,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']]
```

However, it gave an error message saying that str objects cannot be placed in arrays. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
landscape = [['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,X'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['O,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']]
```

You forgot to separate the elements of the array with a comma (,)
Use the code above

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple typo. By not separating the inner arrays by commas, you're actually indexing into the first array you wrote, and strings can't be indices. The proper way to write this is:

```
landscape = [['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,X'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'],
['O,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']]
```

I'm guessing you also want those strings to look like `'-', '-'`, etc., rather than one single string with commas in it.

## An Easier Way:

Python also lets you "multiply" strings to produce a list of certain length, like so:

```
['-'] * 5
```

which produces the list `['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']`

So you could use that in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
[['-'] * 5 for _ in range(5)]
```

to produce:

```
[['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]
```